# How to get the name of the variable with the highest value in an array

Tags: excel, vba, variables, max, formulas

So I have the following formula

```
Dim A as integer    
Dim B as integer
Dim C as integer
Dim D as integer
Dim E as integer
Dim F as integer

A=1
B=2
C=3
D=4
E=5
F=6

MaxValue = Application.Max(A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

I need to get the name of the variable which value is the highest (F)

I´m going to get the Maximum Value in the variable MaxValue, So MaxValue will be equal to 6. But How can I get the value of the variable?

Meaning, how can I get the "F"?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the name of a variable?  I suspect that you need some sort of lookup, but knowing what exactly you're trying to accomplish will probably get you a better answer.

Comment: `MaxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(A,B,C,D,E,F) `

Comment: I´m trying to make an action based on who is the highest value. So basically then do something like. `If variableRetunr is A then write this f variableRetunr is A then write this .... `

Comment: That's not part of your original question but it sounds as though you'll want to use `Select Case`. See [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) for more information.

Comment: That´s the explanation of why do I need to get the value. I know how use it after I get it, but I need to get in the first place the name of the variable which value is the highest. Thanks

Comment: Still cannot see why you need the name of the variable. You could do `if a = maxvalue then ...`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  But you can also do this with `Select case maxValue` // `Case A` // `Case B` // etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @BruceWayne this soundsl ike an XY problem but:

```
Dim arrNames, arrVals, m

arrNames = Array("A", "B", "C")
arrVals = Array(1, 3, 2)

m = Application.Match(Application.Max(arrVals), arrVals, 0)

Debug.Print arrNames(m - 1) 'm is 1-based
```

Seems likely you're not hard-coding the actual values as in your question (if that was the case you know the answer before running the code...) but you're getting the values from somewhere else, so it would be useful to explain what your *actual* task is.

Comment: Thanks, It is good to see that there is always someone that understand other´s people problems. Thank you again

Comment: I think that's being a little uncharitable to the other folk who responded to your question. The issue was that the question seemed to present an unlikely situation and ask for a resolution - most people who answer questions here know enough to try to understand the *actual* use case before providing a solution.